# Does uninstalling nodejs removes npm and npx packages?

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

I'm having some vulnerable errors which needs to have manual review when running react app. I tried to fix them but couldn't able to. Now, if I uninstall and reinstall the NodeJs does the above issue get solved??

Comment: You'll still have the same dependency tree in a different version of Node, how would that make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

NO, It only uninstalls node and npm. Installed packages remains as it is.